# How to copy formatted text from Visual Studio into Visio without keeping the format?

Tags: copy-paste, visual-studio, microsoft-visio

I'm copying text from Visual Studio and pasting it in MS-Visio, but I would like to lose the formatting. I already tried using Ctrl+Shift+V but this seems not to be working (Ctr+Shift starts zooming).

In Visual Studio I don't find an option to copy without the formatting, in Visio I don't find an option to paste without the formatting (Keep Text Only is not included in the "Paste Special" options).

Is there a way to do this without needing to pass via an external editor (Notepad, Notepad++, Ultra Edit, ...) in order to lose the formatting? (If possible, I prefer a solution which does not involve installing extra software)

Oh, I almost forgot: I'm working with Visio Pro for Office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio has **Paste Special** from the drop-down arrow under **Paste** on the ribbon and then select **Unformatted Text**.

Comment: Instead of a simple Ctrl+V, you have to to click Paste | select Paste Special | select Unformatted Text | click OK.  :^(   Visio needs an option to turn off Paste as formatted text or to configure the default paste behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/).

It's a small free program which allows you to create a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the default, works well for me) that will paste plain text.

Handy for situations where programs don't have a "paste unformatted" option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I'm looking for a solution without needing to install additional software.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should probably update your question to include that requirement. Right now, the only thing you're excluding is an external editor - hence why I proposed PureText.